# has google ad manager video ads from google?

Tags: google-ad-manager, vast

I have a stream website and I want to show video ads from google on my website . I registered my website on Adsense and then I registered on google ad manger. from inventory menu I added an ad unit and on Tag menu I selected google Publisher tag for video and audio and I selected  google IMA SDk. on last step it generated a tag. when I open this tag on browser , it is a xml page but it is empty and it doesn't have any content.
I want to show video ads from google something like youtube  and I don't want to add my video ads for showing . Can someone help me to fix it ?

Comment: I think what you are looking for are Native Video Ads. Check this out: https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7025311

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information, setup is correct but missing link here is google Adx tag for video, Or Adsense for video product active in order to show the ads.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate in order to improve clarity. What needs to be done to solve the problem?

Comment: For running the video ads via Google Ad Manager, You need 2 things, 1- VAST tags with Google actual advertiser demand and other things is 2- IMA SDK compliant video player. Without Video player you can't show the video ads.

Comment: Please [edit] according to [answer] and to add that info from your comment.